# How can I return to a form after $request->validate() errors with the input data values showing?

Tags: forms, validation, input, laravel-6

I'm using this code below in a Laravel controller but on errors it doesn't keep the input data when it returns to the form.

```
public function store(Request $request)
       {
         $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'intro' => 'required|max:140|min:40',
       ]);
```

If the intro is too short it sends the user back to the form but with empty fields.

The blade looks like this

```
<form action="{{route('member.store')}}" id="form" role="form" data-toggle="validator" method="post">

<div class="form-group">
           <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" id="name"  name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
          </div>
       <div class="form-group">
           <textarea  class="form-control" id="intro" rows="2" name="intro" placeholder="A short 15-30 word intro" required></textarea>
               </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Doesn't is come with a return to the form with the data input?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#old-input

Answer (score 0):

You should use `old('input')` in the value of the input.

For your code it should be like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" id="name"  name="name" placeholder="Name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea  class="form-control" id="intro" rows="2" name="intro" placeholder="A short 15-30 word intro" value="{{ old('intro') }}" required></textarea>
</div>
```